# Algorithmic error in my python program

Tags: python

When I run it, the number of gold coins is only incremented by one, despite the fact that there are three additional gold coins. I do not know what is wrong with my logic. I have created two functions; addToInventory which takes a dictionary as the first parameter and a list as the second parameter. The function adds the key to the dictionary if the key does not exist in the dictionary and increments the value by one. The displayInventory method prints the key/values from the dictionary. Here is my source code:

```
#fantasyGameInventory.py - a function that displays the inventory from a
#dictionary data structure

stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 40, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
dragonLoot = {'gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby'}

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    #Iterate through the list 
    for k in addedItems:
       #if key not in the dictionary, add to the dictionary and set its value to zero
        inventory.setdefault(k,0)
        inventory[k] = inventory[k] + 1
        print(str(inventory[k]))

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    itemTotal = 0
    #iterate through the dictionary and print the key/values
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(k + ': ' + str(v))
        itemTotal = itemTotal + v
        print ('Total number of items: ' + str(itemTotal))

addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

It says there are 41 gold coins, even though obviously there should be 42: the original 40 from `stuff` plus two more in `dragonLoot`.

Comment: is dragonLoot supposed to be a set? i think it should be a list

Comment: there should be 43 - the original 40 plus the three in dragonLoot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define dragonLoot, you're defining a `set`. Sets are orderless and will only have one of a given term. In python, curly braces are used to define either dictionaries or sets- if it's key : value pairs, it's a dict, otherwise it's a set. To keep order and numbering, us either a tuple (defined using (foo,bar,coin,) form typically) or a list (defined using [foo, bar, coin]).

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that error. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to change set to tuple because its skipping duplicate entries while traversing the list.

Here is the working code :

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 40, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
dragonLoot = ('gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby')

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    #Iterate through the list
    for k in addedItems:
        #if key not in the dictionary, add to the dictionary and set its value to zero
        inventory.setdefault(k,0)
        #increment value by one
        inventory[k] = inventory[k] + 1
        print(str(inventory[k]))

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    itemTotal = 0
    #iterate through the dictionary and print the key/values
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(k + ': ' + str(v))
        itemTotal = itemTotal + v
    print ('Total number of items: ' + str(itemTotal))

addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic within your functions is adequate, but your choice of a {set} for the "dragon_loot" data type was illogical ;)

```
'''
started: yyyymmdd@time
fantasyGameInventory.py - a pair of functions which
add items in a list to an inventory dictionary and
display the inventory from a dictionary data structure
finished: yyyymmdd@time
author: your_name_here
'''

stuff = {'rope': 1, # a dict
         'torch': 6,
         'gold coin': 40,
         'dagger': 1,
         'arrow': 12}
dragon_loot = ['gold coin', # a list
               'dagger',
               'gold coin',
               'gold coin',
               'ruby']
dragonLoot = {'gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby'}

print ('"stuff" is a {}'.format(type(stuff)))
print ('"dragon_loot" is a {}, and'.format(type(dragon_loot)))
print ('"dragonLoot" was a {} (with a camelCase binding)'.format(type(dragonLoot)))
print ()
print ('Wha\' happen\' to all the gold???\n{}'.format(dragonLoot))
print ()


def add_to_inventory(inventory_dict, item_list):
    '''
    Iterate through a list of items to be added to an
    inventory dictionary. If key not already in the
    dictionary, it gets added to the dictionary
    and its value set to zero, then the value is updated
    '''
    for item in item_list:
        inventory_dict.setdefault(item, 0)
        inventory_dict[item] += 1
        print('{} {}'.format(str(inventory_dict[item]), str(item)))


def display_inventory(inventory_dict):
    '''
    Display the inventory from a dictionary data structure.
    '''
    print('Inventory contents (unordered):')
    total_num_items = 0
    # iterate through the dictionary and print the 'k'ey/'v'alue pairs
    for k, v in inventory_dict.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, str(v)))
        total_num_items += v
    print ('Total number of items: {}'.format(str(total_num_items)))

add_to_inventory(stuff, dragon_loot)
display_inventory(stuff)
```